# SET DATEFORMAT returns zero records in Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I have a slightly confusing issuse. In SQL Server I run a query that starts with

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;

Then later on it has DateAdded BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-13' for example.

When I run this on SQL Server 2005 Management Studio it returns the results I want. However, when I run the same SQL statement via ADODB in Classic ASP it returns zero records.

If I take out SET DATEFORMAT ymd; the ASP does return records, but not in the correct date format.

Is there any reason why running the query via ASP produces no results but SQL Server Management Studio does produce the results? (They are both running under the same Login too!)

The column is a "datetime"

Comment: It depends how are you calling this sql statement via ASP. can you show your asp code?

Comment: Also what is the data type of the column?

Comment: The column type is "datetime". The ASP is just called like this:

`objRS.Open SQLDate, objConn, 1,1
TotalRecords = objRS.RecordCount`

In this case TotalRecords is 0. But SQL Server would return 50+ records.

Comment: Try adding this line: `objRS.NextRecordSet()` after you Open it. The first statement probably generates its own Recordset.

Comment: No luck with that :( - it just returns "Current provider does not support returning multiple recordsets from a single execution. " So I guess it isnt opening multiple recordsets.

Answer (score 0):

As @ShadowWizard said, try moving to the next recordset.

A more elegant solution is to put `SET NOCOUNT ON` before your query. This stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set.

### Example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; SET DATEFORMAT ymd; select * from YourTable
```

Comment: No luck with that either. Gah, this problem is just madness!